# How to iterate over multiple data sets in a SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm showing a list of tickets based on their status (i.e OPEN). I'm trying to show a specific data point in the list but that specific data point, "computerNumber", is not available in the data set based on status; however, both data sets share a "ticketId". The only way I've been able to show "computerNumber" in any form is to use .onAppear and call the data set with the shared "ticketId", but that shows the same "computerNumber" on all list items based on the most recent list item that has appeared on the screen. What would be the best way to iterate over the secondary data set and show each list item's unique computerNumber?

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ShowSelectedStatus: View {
    @ObservedObject var ticketStatusAction = TicketStatusAction()
    @Binding var userApi: String
    @Binding var tickets: [TicksByStatus]
    @State private var isShowing = false
    @State var ticket: [TicketDetails] = []
    var ticketStatus: String
    var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                List(tickets) { tick in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                        
                        Text(tick.displayClient)
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(self.color)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                        
                        Text(clearMarkdown(on:tick.shortDetail))
                            .font(.system(size: 11))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        
                        Text(ticket.first?.ticketCustomFields.first(where: {$0.definitionId == 11})?.restValue ?? "NOT PROVIDED")
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(
                            id: tick.id,
                            displayClient: tick.displayClient,
                            userApi: self.$userApi
                        )) {
                            Text("See Details")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                            
                                .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                                    Button(
                                        action: {
                                            self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 1);
                                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                                FetchTick().getTicket(id: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in self.ticket = [ticketDetails] }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    )
                                    {Text("Set Status to Open")}
                                    
                                    Button(
                                        action: {
                                            self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 2);
                                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                                FetchTick().getTicket(id: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in self.ticket = [ticketDetails] }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    )
                                    {Text("Set Status to Pending")}
                                    
                                    Button(
                                        action: {
                                            self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 6);
                                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                                FetchTick().getTicket(id: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in self.ticket = [ticketDetails] }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    )
                                    {Text("Set Status to Depot")}
                                    
                                    Button(
                                        action: {
                                            self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 3);
                                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                                FetchTick().getTicket(id: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in self.ticket = [ticketDetails] }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    )
                                    {Text("Close Ticket")}
                                })
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        FetchTick().getTicket(id: tick.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                            self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                        }
                    }
                }
                .refreshable {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        self.isShowing = false
                    }
                    FetchTicksByStatus().getTicksByStatus(
                        ticketStatus: self.ticketStatus,
                        userApi: self.userApi
                    ) {
                        (ticks) in self.tickets = ticks
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: self.isShowing) { value in
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(
                    Text("\(ticketStatus) (\(tickets.count))"),
                    displayMode: .inline
                )
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs a [mre] -- there are many missing types that you refer to in the question and are necessary to run the code.

Comment: And it would be helpful to prune the `View` you posted to the bare minimum.

Comment: You need to rethink your model and simplify your view.  Your views shouldn't contain any significant. "procedural"  code or be making asynchronous calls with completion handlers. The view should request the model to refresh and the model should just publish changed data which triggers the view to refresh. I would suggest that everything inside your `NavigationLink` gets moved to its own View.  You can provide a view model to this object. The view model can fetch the computer id and publish it. This way your view will automatically refresh

Comment: A good way to think about SwiftUI is to write code that works without any views. It just fetches, organises and updates data. Once you have that it is easy to connect the data to views and actions from views back to update methods with nice separation between model and view

Comment: This is the first and only App I've made with Swift. I made it with "spare time" a couple years ago to give us a better way to interact with our Help Desk system. It will be hard to supply a "working example" without exposing sensitive information. What exactly do you mean "without views" @Paulw11 ? Can you link some specific documentation for me to take a look at? Thanks for the patience with my Swift ignorance.